# UIScrollView on custom view xib not scrolling when called via addSubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a custom view with height 800 in XIB as seen on the picture :

[image]

this is the hierarchy :

[image]

this the code on my customView.m :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self setup];
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
NSLog(@"initWithCoder");
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if(self) {
    [self setup];
}
return self;
}

- (void)setup {

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customView" owner:self options:nil];
[self addSubview:self.view];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame));
//[self.myscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 2000)];
NSLog(@"contentSize Height :%f", self.myscrollview.contentSize.height);
NSLog(@"contentView Height :%f", self.contentView.frame.size.height);
}
```

and addSubview the customView on my viewController view :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

customView *myView = [[customView alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:myView];

}
```

it is loaded, but the scrollView is not scrolling. Then I check the customView and contentView height it returns 800 but the scrollView contentSize height it returns 0. so I tried to set the contentSize to 2000 but it still not scrolling. the thing that made me confused is that why after I set the scrollView trailing, leading, bottom and top 0 to superView it is not following the contentView height, instead return 0. How am i supposed to set the contentSize then?

nb: the contentView has height and width equal to superView and the priority set to 250

github : [project example](https://github.com/xeravim/XIBAutoLayout)

Comment: Add proper constraint  to view when you add it as subview.  that will solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294571/how-to-add-constraint-programmatically-in-objective-c/35317238

Comment: i am not doing constraint on code.

Comment: But you should. everything you have at design time is with constraint. and if you dont apply constraint to  view added runtime, it can never give you result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't set frame for `myView`. Replace your `viewDidLoad` method with below code and it will work as expected

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     customView *customV = [[customView alloc] initWithFrame:self.wantToShowHereView.bounds];
    [self.wantToShowHereView addSubview:customV];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! its working not what I expected since the scroll is not scrolling until the last object below, and its super lagi, do you know why?

Comment: What is the last object below? The scroll view in your sample contains only 1 UILabel and it's smooth