# How do you tighten UILabel's sizeToFit to use smaller margins?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I'm creating a `UILabel`, adding some text, and then calling `[myLabel sizeToFit]`, which resizes the label to fit the text. However, I'm noticing some margin -- or edge insets -- to the left and right, almost as if it's purposely buffering my text.

I'm very short on space, and I'd like to run `sizeToFit` without these margins, i.e. I want the last pixel of my text to run up against the bounds on left & right. How do I accomplish this?

```
- (void) layoutGroupTabLabeled:(NSString*)title {
    // Determine how long a label we need:
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = NSLocalizedString(title, @"");
    [label sizeToFit];
}
```

The label should be tight, but has space to left & right.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is using AutoLayout constraints. In your case it should be covered by adding leading and trailing constraints to the label.

If you don't know your way around AutoLayout I recommend checking these answers.
[Adding constraints programmatically in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590903/adding-constraints-programmatically-in-objective-c)